# How to add HTML / Form to an Admin Bar Menu

Tags: plugin-development, admin

I'd like to add a custom form to the admin bar in Wordpress. is there a way to accomplish this? So far all of the documentation seems to only allow the addition of simple text links.

Comment: [This plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/enhanced-admin-bar-with-codex-search/screenshots/) does it, if you happen to get the core of this functionality, please post it here ;o)

Answer (score 6):

I just gave this a shot and it seemed to work fine:

```
function wpse_form_in_admin_bar() {
    global $wp_admin_bar;

    $wp_admin_bar->add_menu( array(
        'id' => 'wpse-form-in-admin-bar',
        'parent' => 'top-secondary',
        'title' => '<form><input type="text" /><input type="submit" /> </form>'
    ) );
}
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'wpse_form_in_admin_bar' );
```

You'll have to do some work to gussy it up a bit, but it looks like there is a chance you can do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

what @tollmanz suggested will probably work, but to avoid having your text breaking out the menu width, I would suggest

```
 function wpse_form_in_admin_bar() {
    global $wp_admin_bar;

    $wp_admin_bar->add_menu( array(
        'id' => 'wpse-form-in-admin-bar',
        'parent' => 'top-secondary',
        'title' => 'title_goes_here',
'meta'   => array(
            'target'   => '_self',
            'html'     => '<!-- Custom HTML that goes below the item --><form><input type="text" /><input type="submit" /> </form>',
        ),

) 

);
}
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'wpse_form_in_admin_bar' );
```

Comment: I think this is much better! The @tollmanz answer is messy a bit! html tags inside an attribute?!!